# Write an aligned table with multiple spaces as delimiters

Tags: r

I want to save an aligned table with multiple spaces as delimiters.

```
table <- data.frame(col1 = c("abc", "ab", "a"),
                    col2 = c("a", "ab", "c"))
```

Expected output should look like table with different number of spaces as delimiters but columns should have equal width

```
col1 col2
abc  a
ab   ab
a    c
```

something like this
[image]

Comment: This is unclear. What is the expected output?

Comment: sorry, added this to description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `print.data.frame`:

```
print(table, right = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
 #col1 col2
 #abc  a   
 #ab   ab  
 #a    c
```

`format.data.frame` might also be of interest as it lets you specify a minimum width and actually pads the character strings with blank spaces.

It is unclear, what you mean by "save" but that might involve `capture.output` or `sink`.